# R: extract string before and after keyword

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract the string before certain keywords and the first element right after the keyword. Given the following strings and the keywords,

```
s <- c("E123Apple12", "EJ23ZGrape0Z", "J8BananaZ!")
keywords <- c("Apple", "Grape", "Banana")
```

I would expect the output to be: `E123`, `EJ23Z`, and `J8` for strings before the keywords, and `1`, `0`, and `Z` for the first element that appears right after the keyword.

Using `sub(keywords, "\\1", s)` gives me the following error:

```
Warning message:
In sub(keywords, "\\", s) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keywords need to be a regex string, rather than an R vector representing multiple matches. Then you can replace any matching keyword with an empty string, leaving just the characters around it:

```
keywords <- "(Apple|Grape|Banana)"
sub(keywords, "", s) # [1] "E123"  "EJ23Z" "J8"
```

If you want just the characters before or after the keyword, you can match them with `.*`:

```
s <- c("E123AppleABC", "EJ23ZGrapeDEF", "J8BananaGHI")
keywords <- "(Apple|Grape|Banana).*"
sub(keywords, "", s) # [1] "E123"  "EJ23Z" "J8"

keywords <- ".*(Apple|Grape|Banana)"
sub(keywords, "", s) # [1] "ABC"  "DEF" "GHI"
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you take a look at my modified post above?

Comment: How would I extract the first element right after the keyword? Instead of everything after the keyword

Comment: If by first element you mean character, just omit the `*`. With regular expressions, the `.` means match any character (once) and the `*` means match the previous as many times as possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, that extracts everything except the first element. You can match the first character in the regex: `keywords <- "(Apple|Grape|Banana)(.).*"` and then when you `sub`, replace with the second match: `sub(keywords, "\\2", s)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have parallel vectors one way to do this would be to use strsplit, but you'll need to massage the result a little.

```
strsplit(s, keywords)
```

Results in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "E123" "12"  

[[2]]
[1] "EJ23Z" "0Z"   

[[3]]
[1] "J8" "Z!"
```

You need to select the first member in each list and combine into a vector like this:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, keywords), "[[", 1))
```

Which outputs

```
[1] "E123"  "EJ23Z" "J8"
```

If you want what's after the string just do

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, keywords), "[[", 2))
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind,strsplit(s,keywords))`

Answer (score 1):

```
keywords <- "(Apple|Grape|Banana)"
sub(paste0("(.*)",keywords,".*"),'\\1',s)
[1] "E123"  "EJ23Z" "J8"   
sub(paste0(".*",keywords,"(\\w)",".*$"),'\\2',s)
[1] "1" "0" "Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x in keywords) {
  s <- gsub(paste0("(.*)", x), "\\1", s)
}
s
# [1] "E123"  "EJ23Z" "J8"
```